# C# Extension Class not working in Visual Studio 2013, works in 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

The purpose of the code is to allow me to override System Globalization's translations of months because I couldn't get a direct translation for Islamic months. The Tuple List Ext would allow me to store the short and long name of the foreign months with a clean syntax.

My Tuple List Extension Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Business.Extensions
{
    public static class TupleListExt
    {
        public static void Add<T1, T2>(this IList<Tuple<T1, T2>> list,
            T1 item1, T2 item2)
        {
            list.Add(Tuple.Create(item1, item2));
        }
    }
}
```

Using this extension:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Business.Extensions;

public List<Tuple<string, string>> Months
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<Tuple<string, string>>{
                    {"",""}, // 0 index
                    {"يناير",   "يناير"}, //January, Jan
                    {"فبراير",  "فبراير"}, //Feb
                    {"مارس",    "مارس"}, // Mar
                    {"إبريل",   "إبريل"}, //April
                    {"مايو",    "مايو"}, // May
                    {"يونيو",   "يونيو"}, //June
                    {"يوليو",   "يوليو"}, //July
                    {"أغسطس",   "أغسطس"}, //Aug
                    {"سبتمبر",  "سبتمبر"}, //Sept
                    {"أكتوبر",  "أكتوبر"}, //Oct
                    {"نوفمبر",  "نوفمبر"}, //Nov
                    {"ديسمبر",  "ديسمبر"}, //Dec
                };
            }
        }
```

This works GREAT in Visual Studio 2015, and the code works as expected in production, but I have other devs working with me using VS 2013 and it fails to build with this error:

> No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments

After building with 2015, 2013 seems to build just fine, but after I touch the file again it breaks.

I am assuming this has something to do with resolving the namespace extension type Add, but I am new to C# and am stuck!

Comment: I believe that support for extension methods for that syntax was introduced with Roslyn, the new compiler, that is only available in Visual Studio 2015 right now. You're probably going to have to initialize it with actual tuples, `new ... { Tuple.Create("...", "..."), Tuple.Create("...", "...") ... };`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippet makes use of the C# 6 feature not available in VS 2013. Namely, it relies upon a fix to C# compiler that [allows implicit calls of extension method `Add` from collection initializers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6):

> When we first implemented collection initializers in C#, the `Add` methods that get called couldn’t be extension methods. VB got it right from the start, but it seems we forgot about it in C#. This has been fixed: the code generated from a collection initializer will now happily call an extension method called `Add`. It’s not much of a feature, but it’s occasionally useful, and it turned out implementing it in the new compiler amounted to removing a check that prevented it.

Unfortunately, the work-around to this problem is to call `Tuple.Create` explicitly inside your initializer.